# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Image Url Error Code 302 Redirection

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, https, http-status-code-302, imageurl

ASP.NET Core 3.1 Website hosted on Windows server with IIS using https.

**When trying to access images in a particular folder, the image fails to display and the request redirects to sign-in page.**

Examples of image paths that fail with redirect:

https://example.com/samadhi/staff/6890.jpg

https://example.com/samadhi/staff/logo2.jpg

Examples of image paths that are working:

https://example.com/samadhi/mms/qrcode15.jpg

https://example.com/samadhi/body_map.jpg

- I have other folders with images that work fine - it's happening to images in just one folder.
- I checked folder and file permissions but they are all the same with full access.
- I tried deleting the folder & files and re-uploading them but no change.
- When originally hosting the site these images were working fine.
- The problem started just a few weeks ago.
- I added a text file to the folder for testing but that also redirects.

In Plesk control panel I see "IIS access" entries like the following:

```
302 GET /samadhi/staff/UserPic.jpg - HTTP/2
302 GET /samadhi/staff/318.jpg - HTTP/1.1
```

Other more verbose "ModSecurity" entries show like this:

```
3891110101670432115 124.171.83.143 80 127.0.0.1 80
--6c3d0000-B--
GET /samadhi/staff/6890.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: example.net.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; Zoom 3.6.0)

--6c3d0000-F--
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

--6c3d0000-H--
Message: Warning. Match of "pm AppleWebKit Android" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent" required. [file "C:\/Program Files (x86)/Plesk/ModSecurity/rules/modsecurity_crs-plesk/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf"] [line "1228"] [id "920300"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-protocol"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/210/272"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"]
Apache-Handler: IIS
Stopwatch: 1632221945009248 4997 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1632221945009248 4997; combined=4997, p1=4997, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=0, sr=4997, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for IIS (STABLE)/2.9.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/3.3.0.
Server: ModSecurity Standalone
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"

--6c3d0000-Z--
--84670000-A--
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
                {
                    o.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(90, 0, 0, 0);
                    o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Samadhi/SignIn/");
                    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Samadhi/SignIn/");
                    o.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Samadhi/SignOut/");
                    var defaultCallback = o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin;
                    o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/samadhi"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.RedirectUri = "/Samadhi/SignIn/";
                            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        else if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/consultant"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.RedirectUri = "/Consultant/SignIn/";
                            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        else if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/candidate"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.RedirectUri = "/Candidate/SignIn/";
                            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        return defaultCallback(context);
                    };                        
                    o.Validate();
                });

            services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();

            services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions>(o =>
            {
                // Password settings
                o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                o.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings
                o.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                o.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings
                o.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            // add detection services container and device resolver service
            services.AddDetectionCore()
                .AddDevice();

            // google recaptcha
            services.Configure<ReCAPTCHASettings>(Configuration.GetSection("GooglereCAPTCHA"))
                .AddTransient<ReCAPTCHAService>();

            // services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAntiforgery();
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        try
        {
            // set file path
            gFunc.SetLogFilePaths(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

            // environment
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();                
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings.Add(".exe", "application/octect-stream");

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "canvas")),
                RequestPath = "/canvas",
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
                DefaultContentType = "plain/text",
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });

            provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
            provider.Mappings.Add(".exe", "application/octect-stream");
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "samadhi")),
                RequestPath = "/samadhi",
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
                DefaultContentType = "plain/text",
                ContentTypeProvider = provider
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Samadhi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\tmp"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests>
        <clear/>
      </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: b79c90dc-200d-42a3-a1c4-d3d389a66244-->
```

Comment: Can you share your startup.cs? Worth looking into how your auth is determined there. And the path that has the problem is just something like domain.com/images?

Comment: @BenMatthews ok I've added extra info including Startup.cs

Comment: Sadly, nothing is jumping out at me as a culprit for that problem right away. It may be in the code, but perhaps in plesk or something else. Are these images referenced in the html in an img tag for the ones that work as well as the ones that don't.

Comment: Did you set any url rewrite rule on IIS? Can you show the web.config?

Comment: @BruceZhang i only have access to IIS via Plesk as its shared hosting, but I've never set any url rewrite rules. i've updated my post to include web.config

Comment: @BenMatthews most of the images are not used in the site itself. they are referenced from other apps.

Comment: @RossKelly The error message mentions a bit about missing the correct accept header for the request to the images. Have you tried accessing them in a client you can control to eliminate the client request isn't the issue? Or a traffic log that includes header info?

Comment: @BenMatthews I'm accessing the images in two ways: (1) a simple url in Chrome browser, (2) images in a WPF desktop app. I've tried using Postman but that returns 200 ok and the html of the sign-in page.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me!

One of the controllers for my site (a controller named "Samadhi") has a route simply called “Staff”. I completely forgot about this route and of course it conflicts with the image path (static file path: /samadhi/staff/001.jpg)

I renamed the route to "ManageStaff" and now the image url's are working fine.

The offending route:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = gFunc.CLAIM_ROLE_SAMADHI_SHOP)]
public async Task<ViewResult> Staff()
{
}
```